# eth0 not appearing. Tried everything that seemed to work for other people

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

Firstly, let me say I am completely new to Linux so if you're going to tell me to check something or do something, please give me a vague idea how.

Installed Ubuntu Server (newest download I could) and now struggling to get `eth0` to even be detected. The only interface being displayed is the `loopback` interface, and `eth0` (which should be a wired PCI ethernet card) is nowhere to be found.

`ifconfig` shows only the `loopback` device, `/etc/network/interfaces` has only these two lines in:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried opening the file in `nano` (using `sudo`) and adding the lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

but no luck. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> should save according to the web but every time I go back to check the file the two lines I added are gone.

Tried going to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, however all it says is:

```
# This file maintains persistent names for network interfaces.
# See udev(7) for syntax.
#
# Entries are automatically added by the 75-persistent-net-generator.rules
# file; however you are free to add your own entries.
```

That is all it says.

It worked fine in Windows, and I desperately need to get some actual work done on Linux. Can anyone please shed any light on this issue? Every other forum entry I have read has a suggested solution that works and then everyone goes "oh great thanks" and I'm stuck here not having a clue.

EDIT:
After loading the e1000e module, nothing changes when I lspci. Here is the output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 0100 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 0102 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c3a (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1503 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c2d (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c20 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c10 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c26 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c5c (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c02 (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c22 (rev 05)
```

When I used the verbose switch, the ethernet controller is as follows:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1503 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Unknown device 8000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
        Memory at fe400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at fe428000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [d0] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
        Capabilities: [e0] #13 [0306]
```

ifconfig still outputs the same result after loading e1000e (loopback device only).

Comment: Does it show up if you type `ifconfig -a`? If so, you can online it with `ifup eth0`.

Comment: Nope. All that shows up is the loopback device. I have also tried installing the correct drivers, which, as far as I could tell, installed correctly, but to no avail.

Comment: Does your network adapter appear under `lspci`?

Comment: Aha, now we're getting somewhere. One of the entries is

    00:19.0 Ethernet Controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1503 (rev 05)

Comment: Yeah, looks like the driver is missing for the device. Try `modprobe e1000e`.

Comment: Did that, no confirmation of anything but I didn't get a message telling me it was unsuccessful (ran it with sudo). lspci still shows unknown device though :(

Comment: That command should load a module (a driver), what was the message you got? That the module was not found or that it could not be loaded?

Comment: No message at all, it just goes back to the command line. If it helps the computer is an Acer Aspire X1930, the official Acer site only provides Windows drivers too.

Comment: OK, in that case the module was loaded, you can check by running `lsmod | grep e1000e`. First, could you please [edit] the question to include the result of `lspci`? Also the output of `ifconfig` after `e1000e` has been loaded.

Comment: Same problem here. Although, for me lspci shows `Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet COnnection (2) 1218-V`. But still the only entry in ifconfig is the `lo` (loopback). @Adam: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I see it's an Intel adapter. But what is the actual model? What did windows show the device as when it worked? You should be able to get the drivers manually and do this.